# How to add list of authorized tenant in Multi-tenant app in Aure AD?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, multi-tenant

I developp a multi-tenant app in ASP.NET MVC host in my Azure tenant. I want my app to be available to only the tenant I want and not all tenants. I know that I can add a list of authorized tenant but I don't know how to achieve this.

Any advices ?

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such setting in Azure Active Directory. The options around 'tenancy' are multi-tenant or single-tenant. Multi-tenant means that technically all tenants could get an access token for your service.

However, you can check the Azure documentation on multitenancy points to an example applicaiton called [Tailpsin.Surveys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/run-the-app). This example is where application sign up a new tenant and Add application roles to users.

On the another approach, you can also keep a whitelist of tenants which are allowed to call your API, and check that the token has the correct issuer or tid claim.

Comment: Thank's for your answer !